# Testing React components that fetches data using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks, react-test-renderer

My React-application has a component that fetches data to display from a remote server. In the pre-hooks era, `componentDidMount()` was the place to go. But now I wanted to use hooks for this.

```
const App = () => {
  const [ state, setState ] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(setState);
  });
  return (
    <div>... data display ...</div>
  );
};
```

And my test using Jest and Enzyme looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from './App';
import { act } from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.mock('./api');

import { fetchData } from './api';

describe('<App />', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', (done) => {
    fetchData.mockImplementation(() => {
      return Promise.resolve(42);
    });
    act(() => mount(<App />));
    setTimeout(() => {
      // expectations here
      done();
    }, 500);
  });  
});
```

The test succeeds, but it logs a few warnings:

```
console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):

    act(() => {
    /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */

    This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at (redacted)
        in App (created by WrapperComponent)
        in WrapperComponent
```

The only update to the App component happens from the Promise callback. How can I ensure this happens *within* the `act` block? The docs clearly suggest to have assertions happen *outside* the `act` block. Besides, putting them inside doesn't change the warning.

Comment: This code will call `fetchData` twice or go to an infinite loop if `fetchData` returns different data. You should pass `[]` as second argument to `useEffect` to emaulate `componentDidMount`. Otherwise `useEffect` will be called on every render. First `fetchData` causes a rerender. And it will cause additional renders whenever `setState` gets a new value.

Comment: https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/281#issuecomment-461221880 seems like such cases are under discussion

Comment: I'm not sure but https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples looks promising

Comment: Thanks @UjinT34 for the remark. In fact, I had `[]` as deps, but figured it wasn't relevant for this particular question. Indeed, it should be there to prevent invoking `fetchData` too often. Still, the warning about not using `act` is there :(

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @skyboyer. The point with the repo you refer to is that they use "manual" mocks, which they can manually resolve - inside an `act` statement. I prefer to use Jests mocking possibilities instead. My feeling is that resolving the Promise from the Jest mock happens outside `act`, thus triggering the warning. But I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 24):

That issue is caused by many updates inside Component.

I got the same issue, this would solve the issue.

```
await act( async () => mount(<App />));
```

Comment: I get `Warning: Do not await the result of calling TestRenderer.act(...), it is not a Promise.`

Answer (score 6):

I have created examples for testing async hooks.

https://github.com/oshri6688/react-async-hooks-testing

`CommentWithHooks.js`:

```
import { getData } from "services/dataService";

const CommentWithHooks = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    getData()
      .then(data => {
        setData(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setData("No Data");
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <span data-test-id="loading">Loading...</span>
      ) : (
        <span data-test-id="data">{data}</span>
      )}

      <button
        style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
        data-test-id="btn-refetch"
        onClick={fetchData}
      >
        refetch data
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`CommentWithHooks.test.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import MockPromise from "testUtils/MockPromise";
import CommentWithHooks from "./CommentWithHooks";
import { getData } from "services/dataService";

jest.mock("services/dataService", () => ({
  getData: jest.fn(),
}));

let getDataPromise;

getData.mockImplementation(() => {
  getDataPromise = new MockPromise();

  return getDataPromise;
});

describe("CommentWithHooks", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("when fetching data successed", async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<CommentWithHooks />);
    const button = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="btn-refetch"]');
    let loadingNode = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="loading"]');
    let dataNode = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="data"]');

    const data = "test Data";

    expect(loadingNode).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(loadingNode.text()).toBe("Loading...");

    expect(dataNode).toHaveLength(0);

    expect(button).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(button.prop("onClick")).toBeInstanceOf(Function);

    await getDataPromise.resolve(data);

    wrapper.update();

    loadingNode = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="loading"]');
    dataNode = wrapper.find('[data-test-id="data"]');

    expect(loadingNode).toHaveLength(0);

    expect(dataNode).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(dataNode.text()).toBe(data);
  });
```

`testUtils/MockPromise.js`:

```
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

const createMockCallback = callback => (...args) => {
  let result;

  if (!callback) {
    return;
  }

  act(() => {
    result = callback(...args);
  });

  return result;
};

export default class MockPromise {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.promiseResolve = resolve;
      this.promiseReject = reject;
    });
  }

  resolve(...args) {
    this.promiseResolve(...args);

    return this;
  }

  reject(...args) {
    this.promiseReject(...args);

    return this;
  }

  then(...callbacks) {
    const mockCallbacks = callbacks.map(callback =>
      createMockCallback(callback)
    );

    this.promise = this.promise.then(...mockCallbacks);

    return this;
  }

  catch(callback) {
    const mockCallback = createMockCallback(callback);

    this.promise = this.promise.catch(mockCallback);

    return this;
  }

  finally(callback) {
    const mockCallback = createMockCallback(callback);

    this.promise = this.promise.finally(mockCallback);

    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: This implementation appears to test if the button has a function and that after the mocked getData is called, the UI changes successfully; but how is it checking that clicking the button will call getData? Shouldn't we mimic the user event exactly as it is?

Answer (score 4):

Enzyme doesn't have support for hooks since it's a relatively new feature: 
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2011

Maybe you can use plain Jest in the meantime?
Also don't worry about the warning, it's supposed to go away when React 16.9.0 is released (see this pull request https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14853)

Comment: Note that the PR mentioned in the last half describes the async version of `act`, which you'll have to adopt for the message to "go away". Plain jest wouldn't address it either.

Comment: @erich2k8 you're right. In any case, when I upgraded to React 16.9.0 the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I had that exact same problem, and ended up writing a library that solves this issue by mocking all the standards React Hooks.

Basically, `act()` is a synchronous function, like `useEffect`, but `useEffect` executes an async function. There's no way that act() would be able to "wait" for that to execute. Fire and forget!

Article here: https://medium.com/@jantoine/another-take-on-testing-custom-react-hooks-4461458935d4

Library here: https://github.com/antoinejaussoin/jooks

To test your code, you would first need to extract your logic (the fetch, etc.) into a separate custom hook: something like:

```
const useFetchData = () => {
  const [ state, setState ] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {     
    fetchData().then(setState);
  });
  return state;
}
```

Then, using Jooks, your test would look like:

```
import init from 'jooks';
[...]
describe('Testing my hook', () => {
  const jooks = init(() => useFetchData());

  // Mock your API call here, by returning 'some mocked value';

  it('Should first return 0', () => {
    const data = jooks.run();
    expect(data).toBe(0);
  });

  it('Then should fetch the data and return it', async () => {
    await jooks.mount(); // Fire useEffect etc.
    const data = jooks.run();
    expect(data).toBe('some mocked value');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I resolved this issue using below steps

1. Update react and react-dom to 16.9.0 version.
2. Install regenerator-runtime
3. import regenerator-runtime  in setup file.

   ```
   import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
   import { configure } from "enzyme";
   import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

   configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
   });
   ```
4. Wrap mount and other possible actions which are going to cause state changes inside act. import act from simple react-dom/test-utils, async & await like below.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { mount } from 'enzyme';
   import App from './App';
   import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";

   jest.mock('./api');

   import { fetchData } from './api';

   describe('<App />', () => {
   it('renders without crashing',  async (done) => {
     fetchData.mockImplementation(() => {
       return Promise.resolve(42);
     });
     await act(() => mount(<App />));
     setTimeout(() => {
       // expectations here
       done();
     }, 500);
    });  
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.