# When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have this test:

```
import {
  render,
  cleanup,
  waitForElement
} from '@testing-library/react'

const TestApp = () => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useFetch<Person>('https://example.com', { onMount: true });

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <div data-testid="loading">loading...</div>}
      {error && <div data-testid="error">{error.message}</div>}
      {data && 
        <div>
          <div data-testid="person-name">{data.name}</div>
          <div data-testid="person-age">{data.age}</div>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
};

  describe("useFetch", () => {
    const renderComponent = () => render(<TestApp/>);

    it('should be initially loading', () => {
      const { getByTestId } = renderComponent();

      expect(getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
    })
  });
```

The test passes but I get the following warning:

> Warning: An update to TestApp inside a test was not wrapped in
>   act(...).
>
> ```
> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
>
> act(() => {
>   /* fire events that update state */
> });
> /* assert on the output */
>
> This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser
>     in TestApp
> ```
>
> console.error
>   node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
>       Warning: An update to TestApp inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
>
> ```
> When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
>
> act(() => {
>   /* fire events that update state */
> });
> /* assert on the output */
>
> This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser
>     in TestApp
> ```

Comment: Read https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/281

Answer (score 109):

The key is to `await` `act` and then use `async` arrow function.

```
await act( async () => render(<TestApp/>));
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839513/3850405

Comment: that source is using enzyme mount but here the post is using the react testing library, personally I tried this without success

Comment: Worked for me when using react-hook-form.

Comment: If you vote down please comment why. Hard to improve answers otherwise

Comment: This worked for me!!

Comment: This worked for me and I'm using renderHook from the @testing-library/react (version 13.2.0) in React 18

Comment: Lots of fancy solutions out there that didn't work for me, then this one-liner solution did the miracle. Thanks op. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm using Jest and RTL for unit tests in a React TypeScript application. This worked for me as well. You would only need to wrap your render like so `await act(()=> render(...))` Worked like a charm indeed.

Comment: worked using 
@testing-library/react
@testing-library/jest-dom

This issue displayed from a component contained in another component did this and worked flawlessly.

Comment: What's the `async` for?

Comment: I'm downvoting this because the simultaneous use of `act`, `async` and `render` in one statement has shadowed the real reason that this works. The only part that works is `await`. Add `await waitFor(() => {})` below the `render` line also works. See my answer.

Answer (score 55):

Try asserting inside 'await waitFor()' - for this your it() function should be async

```
it('should be initially loading', async () => {
  const { getByTestId } = renderComponent();

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Keep calm and happy coding

Answer (score 8):

Try using await inside act

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
await act(async () => {
            wrapper = mount(Commponent);
            wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
        });
```

Comment: This worked for me, though I'm not really sure why? The example here is very similar to my code, there is nothing awaited in the inner function, and we aren't returning any other promise, so it seems like it should just be a promise that returns immediately. I guess it just waits until the next tick, which is enough?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same issue which gets resolved by using async queries (findBy*) instead of getBy* or queryBy*.

```
expect(await screen.findByText(/textonscreen/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Async query returns a Promise instead of element, which resolves when an element is found which matches the given query. The promise is rejected if no element is found or if more than one element is found after a default timeout of 1000ms. If you need to find more than one element, use findAllBy.

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

But as you know it wont work properly if something is not on screen. So for `queryBy*` one might need to update test case accordingly

[Note: Here there is no user event just simple render so findBy will work otherwise we need to put user Event in act ]

Answer (score 2):

```
    test('handles server ok', async () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Login />
      </MemoryRouter>
    )

    await waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('register')))

    let domInfo
    await waitFor(() => (domInfo = screen.getByRole('infoOk')))

    // expect(domInfo).toHaveTextContent('登陆成功')
  })
```

I solved the problem in this way,you can try it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

React app with react testing library:

I tried a lot of things, what worked for me was to wait for something after the fireevent so that nothing happens after the test is finished.

In my case it was a calendar that opened when the input field got focus. I fireed the focus event and checked that the resulting focus event occured and finished the test. I think maybe that the calendar opened after my test was finished but before the system was done, and that triggered the warning. Waiting for the calendar to show before finishing did the trick.

```
fireEvent.focus(inputElement);

await waitFor(async () => {
  expect(await screen.findByText('December 2022')).not.toBeNull();
});
expect(onFocusJestFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
// End
```

Hopes this helps someone, I just spent half a day on this.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning in `react-testing-library (RTL)`. you do not have to use `act` in RTL because it is already using it behind the scenes. If you are not using `RTL`, you have to use `act`

```
import {act} from "react-dom/test-utils"
test('',{
    act(()=>{
        render(<TestApp/>)
    })
})
```

You will see that warning when your component does data fetching. Because data fetching is async, when you render the component inside `act()`, behing the scene all the data fetching and state update will be completed first and then `act()` will finish. So you will be rendering the component, with the latest state update

Easiest way to get rid of this warning in RTL, you should run async query functions `findBy*`

```
test("test", async () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter>
      <TestApp />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  await screen.findByRole("button");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the stack of the act error, but I guess, it is triggered by the end of the loading when this causes to change the TestApp state to change and rerender after the test finished. So [waiting for the loading to disappear](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/) at the end of the test should solve this issue.

```
describe("useFetch", () => {
  const renderComponent = () => render(<TestApp/>);

  it('should be initially loading', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = renderComponent();

    expect(getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => queryByTestId('loading'));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the issue [unmount timing leads to "test was not wrapped in act"](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/999). In short, react states are still getting updated even after the test has ended.

One straightforward way is to explicitly unmount before the end of the test:

```
    it('should be initially loading', () => {
      const { getByTestId, unmount } = render(<MyApp/>);
      expect(getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
      unmount();
    })
```

If you are willing to change the test function to be `async`, calling `await waitFor(() => {})` after `render` also works by giving an opportunity for the app to finish updating the states, but this may be less reliable and I would recommend the method above as it cuts the throat of the issue:

```
    it('should be initially loading', async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(<MyApp/>);
      await waitFor(() => {});
      expect(getByTestId('loading')).toBeDefined();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

after you do something that update the state, add this

```
const pause = async (ms) => {
  await act(async () => {
    await sleep(ms || 100);
  });
};
await pause()
```