# Warning: An update to ForwardRef(StickyScrollBar) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have come across this error when attempting to run my test cases.  I have tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722139/when-testing-code-that-causes-react-state-updates-should-be-wrapped-into-act) to no luck.

Here is my test code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { act, render } from '@testing-library/react'
import App from './App'

describe('Renders App Component', () => {
  let getByTestId
  beforeEach(() => {
    const component = render(<App />)
    getByTestId = component.getByTestId
  })

  it('Renders Header Caption', () => {
    const header = getByTestId('header-caption')

    expect(header.textContent).toBe('Data Dashboard')
  })
})
```

Here is the error that I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: Please show a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)