# Warning: An update to HomePage inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

I have this test:

```
const renderComponent = () =>

   act(() => {
      render(
           <MemoryRouter>
               <HomePage/>
               <ErrorPage/>
           </MemoryRouter>
       )
   }
)


it('Should render the Home page if the item is successfully retrieved', async () => {



        act(() => {

            global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
                Promise.resolve({
                    json: () => [{item: 'item1'}]
                })
            ) as jest.Mock

            renderComponent()
        })

            expect(await waitFor(() => screen.getByTestId('HomePage'))).toBeInTheDocument()
    });
```

The test itself passes but I get this console error:

```
   When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

It highlights the `setItem` section of the code as being the issue:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:4000/items`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setItem(data)
            }) }, [])
```

I'm mystified as to what is going on

Comment: Found this related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047535/testing-react-components-that-fetches-data-using-hooks/59839513#59839513

Comment: What happens when you use `findByTestId` instead of waitfor? Like             `expect(await screen.findByTestId('HomePage')).toBeInTheDocument()`